# Gallery of HTML/JS animated graphics

Tags: html5

I'm looking for a few sites where I can browse hundreds of animated graphic effects in well-coded HTML5 and Javascript.

That's it. Just some standards-compliant animation code that I can make trial-and-error modifications to.

Comment: The web has plenty of this website. Do you need something specific?

Answer (score 3):

http://thecodeplayer.com/ looks ok. Not that many experiments though, but a nice interface, video walkthroughs, and the code.